# Apache password protect selective URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter on a website that I need to partially protect with htaccess.
I want to protect all the controllers except one (called api), but also want the folders with static files (like images, css and uploaded stuff) to be available (they're called static and uploads).
So, if someone arrives at example.com/api/something, they would be able to access it, but not example.com/foo/bar nor example.com/foo, for that matter. example.com/static/* should not be protected.

Comment: I need to **password protect** the controllers (all except "api" controller and some folders), not just enable the use of folders.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to help you, but I think using a token in the session maybe a solution for your case , generate random token like "t0k3n" save it in the session , and on each controller that you want to protect create a variable $token= "t0k3n" in the constructor; and check it against the one in the session; so only users with the right token in the session can access that controller,hope that helps